# Dynamic Generic in vue3 component (Composition API)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

dear colleagues, I want to implement the generic feature in a component that I will reuse in many places, here I show you.

**BaseLayout.vue**

```
<template>
    <Button @click="reloadClick" label="Reload"/>
    <slot name="content" :data="data"> </slot>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">

const props = defineProps({
    loadFunction: {
        type: Function,
        required: true
    }
})

const data = ref<T>()

const reloadClick = async () => {
    const response: T = await props.loadFunction(id)
    data.value = response
}
</script>
```

**ModuleAView.vue**

```
<template>
    <BaseLayout :loadFunction="load">
        <template #content="{ data }">
            <input v-model="data."/>
        </template>
    </BaseLayout>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import BaseLayout from '...'
import ServiceModuleA from '...'
import InterfaceModuleA from '...'

const load = async (id: number) => {
    return await Service.fetchById(id)
}
</script>
```

**ModuleBView.vue**

```
<template>
    <BaseLayout :loadFunction="load">
        <template #content="{ data }">
            <input v-model="data."/>
        </template>
    </BaseLayout>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import BaseLayout from '...'
import ServiceModuleB from '...'
import InterfaceModuleB from '...'

const load = async (id: number) => {
    return await Service.fetchById(id)
}
</script>
```

The problem lies in ModuleAView, ModuleBView, etc. Within <template #content="{ data }"> the attributes of the interfaces InterfaceModuleA, InterfaceModuleB, etc. are not mapped.

How can I solve this problem since the project will grow exponentially and I do not want to have to declare all the interfaces within BaseLayout.vue.

Thanks.